# auto deploy express.js server to GCE pm2

Tags: express, github, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a virtual machine running pm2 on google compute engine
What do I need to do in order to auto deploy an express.js server from a GitHub repository?

I have created an SSH key for logging through a user and installed pm2 on the VM

Answer (score 0):

as this question is really opened and there isn't a unique way to do it, I would recommend to check some example like this [1] to get used with the process.

Cheers!

[1] https://medium.com/@aunnnn/automate-digitalocean-deployment-for-node-js-with-git-and-pm2-67a3cfa7a02b